# Getting i/o error on post request for connection timed out using Rest Template

Tags: api, spring-boot, jenkins, resttemplate

Am getting timed out error while doing a post request on Jenkins for deleting job.The job gets deleted but am not getting the response back in my code.
Tried increasing and decreasing time outs, but they threw 400 bad request error
The deletion works only with the timeout as 5000, but I get the I/O error on post request.

Am manually creating instance for Rest Template as my credentials differ for each request

P.S: this works fine when ran locally through postman. Issue occurs only in remote

Below is my code

public class JenkinAuthRestTemplate extends RestTemplate{

```
public JenkinAuthRestTemplate(String password, int readTimeOut, int connectTimeOut) {

    addAuthentication(password, readTimeOut, connectTimeOut);
}

private void addAuthentication(String password, int readTimeOut, int connectTimeOut) {

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(readTimeOut);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(connectTimeOut);
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build());

    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = Collections
            .<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> singletonList(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(password));
    setRequestFactory(new InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory, interceptors));
}

private static class BasicAuthorizationInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {


    private final String password;


    public BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(String password) {

        this.password = (password == null ? "" : password);
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException {

        request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Basic " + (this.password));
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

}

**deleteJob.java**

JenkinAuthRestTemplate restTemplate = new JenkinAuthRestTemplate(
                jenkin.getToken(endpoint), 5000, 5000);
    ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class);
logger.info(response.getStatusCodeValue());